# Breaking down np.where with nested for-loop and if/else statement

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, if-statement, numpy-ndarray

Write Python code equivalent to the following:

```
even_odd = np.where(h % 2 == 0, 'even', 'odd')
```

You should use nested for-loop and if/else statement.

You can start your code as the below:

```
even_odd = np.empty_like(h, dtype="<U4")

  for i in range(h.shape[0]): # i is row index

  for j in range(h.shape[1]): # j is column index
```

You should get the results below:

```
array([['even', 'odd', 'even'],
       ['odd', 'even', 'odd'],
       ['even', 'odd', 'even'],
       ['odd', 'even', 'odd'],
   ['even', 'odd', 'even']], dtype='<U4')
```

---

My Code Input:

```py
even_odd = np.empty_like(h, dtype="<U4")
for i in range(h.shape[0]):
  for j in range(h.shape[1]):
    if (h[i, j] % 2 == 0):
      h[i, j]
    else:
      h[i, j]
```

Output:

```
even_odd

array([['', '', ''],
       ['', '', ''],
       ['', '', ''],
       ['', '', ''],
       ['', '', '']], dtype='<U4')
```

I am trying to breakdown the code but cannot seem to find the solution. I am confused on how to get "even" or "odd" to show up on my array.

Under my if/else statement, I tried print("even") and print("odd") but I get the list above the array as my output:

```
even
odd
even
odd
even
odd
even
odd
even
odd
even
odd
even
odd
even
array([['', '', ''],
       ['', '', ''],
       ['', '', ''],
       ['', '', ''],
       ['', '', '']], dtype='<U4')
```

I feel like I am close as I simply need to find a way to get the list content in the array.
I researched similar questions on here but all of them seem to be from going from for-loop and if/else statement to np.where, I am trying to do the opposite.

Any insight/help would be greatly appreciated, trying to master the basics!

Comment: You're not assigning a value to `h[i, j]`.

Comment: Even if you were, you're supposed to be setting the values of the `even_odd` array.

Comment: As pointed out by others, you are not assigning any values to the array itself. You are missing something like even_odd[i, j] = 'even'.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to assign values to your matrix!

```py
even_odd = np.empty_like(h, dtype="<U4")
for i in range(h.shape[0]):
 for j in range(h.shape[1]):
  if (h[i, j] % 2 == 0):
    even_odd[i, j]='even'
  else:
    even_odd[i, j]='odd'
print(even_odd)
```